# Can not find NavController set

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation, navgraph

I am trying to navigate between fragments, however when I try view.findNavController in the host fragment (login fragment) inside onViewCreated I face this error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.ScrollView{f13c4b8 VFED.V... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f09011e app:id/login_fragment_container} does not have a NavController set

This is my fragment container view inside the activity.

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph_login"
        android:name="com.example.example.fragments.LoginFragment"
        />
```

This is LoginFragment.kt

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false)
    }

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        navController = view.findNavController()
        ...
```

P.S. I use ScrollView as the container of the fragment, I have two navigation graphs (for two activities) and I use splash screen if it is relevant.

I have tried getting the nav controller using fragment, but it did not work either. I have also tried changing scrollview to linearlayout just incase but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```java
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

to the fragment container view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).